# Response of Ktor failed with exception: kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 0: Expected '[, kind: LIST'

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, kmm

I was developing an App in Kotlin Multiplatform, where I try to implement the regular libraries to networking, and local storage: Ktor with SqlDelight.

After set up the right configuration to make KMM compile fine, I try to connect with an API, using Ktor library, but although my implementation, returns 200 code response, I get the above title error:

```
response failed with exception: kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 0: Expected '[, kind: LIST'.
```

Regarding my API.class

```
internal val kotlinxSerializer = KotlinxSerializer(
  Json(
    JsonConfiguration(isLenient = false, ignoreUnknownKeys = true, encodeDefaults = false)
  )
)
internal val ktorClient = HttpClient {
  defaultRequest {
    header("Accept-Version","v1")
    header("Authorization", "Client-ID $CLIENT_ID")
  }
  install(JsonFeature) {
    serializer = kotlinxSerializer
  }
  install(Logging) {
    logger = Logger.DEFAULT
    level = LogLevel.ALL
  }
}
private const val CLIENT_ID : String = "7DQCWc0Hr_GGIOUeMAVKxqvz9lsVtCpvauRvXJnNq_E"
internal const val UNSPLASH_URL = "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos"

//TODO("La resquest al endpoint se inicializa mal")
//TODO("Tras ejecutar la llamada de red en postman, el error es que no le estoy pasando el access token.")

/**
2021-12-18 17:57:25.636 14877-14947/com.jshvarts.kmp.android W/System.err: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient - REQUEST: https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=query&page=page&per_page=per_page
2021-12-18 17:57:25.636 14877-14947/com.jshvarts.kmp.android W/System.err: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient - METHOD: HttpMethod(value=GET)
2021-12-18 17:57:25.638 14877-14947/com.jshvarts.kmp.android W/System.err: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient - COMMON HEADERS
2021-12-18 17:57:25.638 14877-14947/com.jshvarts.kmp.android W/System.err: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Accept: Accept-Version: v1; application/json
2021-12-18 17:57:25.638 14877-14947/com.jshvarts.kmp.android W/System.err: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Accept-Charset: UTF-8
2021-12-18 17:57:25.639 14877-14947/com.jshvarts.kmp.android W/System.err: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient - CONTENT HEADERS
2021-12-18 17:57:25.640 14877-14947/com.jshvarts.kmp.android W/System.err: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient - BODY Content-Type: null
2021-12-18 17:57:25.704 14877-14947/com.jshvarts.kmp.android W/System.err: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient - BODY START
2021-12-18 17:57:25.705 14877-14947/com.jshvarts.kmp.android W/System.err: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient -
2021-12-18 17:57:25.705 14877-14947/com.jshvarts.kmp.android W/System.err: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient - BODY END
2021-12-18 17:57:25.974 1547-3158/? D/CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
 */

class UnsplashApi(private val client: HttpClient = ktorClient) {

  suspend fun getPets(): List<UnsplashPhoto>? = client.get(UNSPLASH_URL){
    //parameter("client_id", CLIENT_ID)
    parameter("query", "cats")
    parameter("page", 1)
    parameter("per_page", 10)
  }
  //TODO("Actualizar el endpoint para incorporar la funcionalidad de buscar por nombre")
  suspend fun getPetsByName(pet: String): List<UnsplashPhoto>? = client.get<List<UnsplashPhoto>>(UNSPLASH_URL){
    parameter("query", pet)
    parameter("page", 1)
    parameter("per_page", 10)
  }
}
```

And regarding my repository, where I use the Ktor libraries to recover the data from API, is the following:
`
PetsRepository.kt

```
internal expect fun cache(): PetsDatabase

class PetsRepository(
  private val api: UnsplashApi,
  private val queries: PetsDBQueries = cache().petsDBQueries
) {
  constructor() : this(api = UnsplashApi())

  /**
   * If [force] is set to true, attempt to load data from remote api.
   * If remote api is not available. throw [RefreshDataException]
   *
   * If [force] is set to false, attempt to load data from local cache.
   * If local cache is not available, propagate the exception encountered
   */
  fun fetchMembersAsFlow(force: Boolean): Flow<List<Pets>> {
    return if (force) getMembersFromRemote() else getMembersFromCache()
  }

  private fun cacheMembers(pets: List<Pets>) {
    queries.deleteAll()
    pets.forEach { pet ->
      queries.insertPet(
          pet.id,
          pet.description,
          pet.url,
          pet.email
      )
    }
  }
  /**
   * Retorna un Flow con una lista de Pets, y guardando en la BD local
   * los pets recuperados de la llamada de red.
   */
  private fun getMembersFromRemote(): Flow<List<Pets>> {
    println("Getting members from remote")

    return flow {
      val unsplashPhotos = api.getPets()
      Log.d("info",  "size pets llamada de red: ${unsplashPhotos!!.size}")
      Log.d("info", "pets $unsplashPhotos")
      //TODO(""Convert UnplashPhoto o Pets")
      var pets : List<Pets> = unsplashPhotos!!.map {
        Pets(it.id!!.toLong(), it.description!!, it.urls.full, it.user.name)
      }
      cacheMembers(pets)
      emit(pets)
    }
        .catch { error(RefreshDataException()) }
        .flowOn(applicationDispatcher)
  }

  private fun getMembersFromCache(): Flow<List<Pets>> {
    println("Getting members from cache")
    fun loadMembers() = queries.selectAll()
        .executeAsList()
        .map { Pets(id = it.id, description = it.description, url = it.url, email = it.emailUser) }
    return flow { emit(loadMembers()) }
        .catch { error(RefreshDataException()) }
        .flowOn(applicationDispatcher)
  }
}
```

Regarding my models.

Pets.kt

```
@Serializable
class Pets (
  @SerialName("id") val id: Long,
  @SerialName("description")val description: String,
  @SerialName("url")val url: String,
  @SerialName("email")val email: String
)
```

UnplashPhoto.kt

```
@Serializable
data class UnsplashPhoto(
  @SerialName ("id")val id: String?,
  @SerialName ("description")val description: String?,
  @SerialName ("urls")val urls: UnsplashPhotoUrls,
  @SerialName ("user")val user: UnsplashUser
)

  @Serializable
  data class UnsplashPhotoUrls(
    @SerialName("raw")  val raw: String,
    @SerialName("full")  val full: String,
    @SerialName("regular")  val regular: String,
    @SerialName("small") val small: String,
    @SerialName("thumb")  val thumb: String
  )

  @Serializable
  data class UnsplashUser(
    val name: String,
    val username: String,
    val attributionUrl : String
  )
    //get() =
    //  "https://unsplash.com/$username?utm_source=ImageSearchApp&utm_medium=referral"
```

The other structure is a regular MVVM patern, where I used the ViewModel, to pass the data in form of Flow. But the main point is it seems that Ktor need at some point to deserialize thhe response, and I guess i should be at the UnplashApi.kt level.

I'm reading by some forus too, and the differents solution they suggest, like put the 'isLenient = false' and 'encodeDefault = false' in the JsonConfiguration of KotlinxSerializer.

I hope you can help, and if like this take thanks in advance !

[EDIT]

After the suggestion of @AlekseiTirman I change the code of my UnplashhApi.kt like this, but although the response code is 200, and the data is loaded correctly to the response, still doesn't work:

UnplashAPi.kt

```
class UnsplashApi(private val client: HttpClient = ktorClient) {      
                                                                      
  suspend fun getPets(): UnsplashReponse? = client.get(UNSPLASH_URL){ 
    //parameter("client_id", CLIENT_ID)                               
    parameter("query", "cats")                                        
    parameter("page", 1)                                              
    parameter("per_page", 10)                                         
  }
```

added 2 pictures of the logcat showing the data:

[image]

[image]

[EDIT]

After debugging the app, I saw the flow of the data is correct until I try to transform my List of UnsplashPhoto into a List of Pets in the repository class, when I try to map it.

Comment: The Unsplash API documentation https://unsplash.com/documentation#search-photos says that the response is a JSON object but you expect a list (array). The list of photos is defined in the `results` key of that object.

Comment: Okey, so I should return from my api call a JSONObject, which transform after in my repository to a List of my entity?

Comment: You should receive an instance of the `data class UnsplashPhotoResponse(results: List<UnsplashPhoto>)`.

Comment: Aleksei Tirman I added your suggestion and still doen't show any data on screen, although the data is recover from the api. I also added 2 pcture of the logcat showing the call.

Comment: Did you get the same error? What the `getPets()` method call returns?

Comment: As I have right now,  the method getPets() return an UnsplashResponse, which contains a  List of UnsplashPhoto.

Comment: After debugging, I see that everything flow well until I try to map the list of the response of getPets() method, where it's seems the data get lost.